# How to scale mysql table to keep historic data without increasing table size

Tags: mysql, django

I have a questionnaire in my app, using which I am creating data corresponding to the user who has submitted it and at what time(I have to apply further processing on the last object/questionnaire per user). This data is saved inside my server's MySQL DB. As this questionnaire is open for all my users and as it will be submitted multiple times, I do not want new entries to be created every time for the same user because this will increase the size of the table(users count could be anything around 10M), But I also want to keep the old data as a history for later processing.

Now I have this option in mind:
Create two tables. One main table to keep new objects and one history table to keep history objects. Whenever a questionnaire is submitted it will create a new entry in the history table, but update the existing entry in the main table.

So, is there any better approach to this and how do other companies tackle such situations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through the SCD (Slowly Changing Dimension) Concepts and decide which one is better approach to you.

Please read this and i think you will find the best way for yourself :

[Here](https://adatis.co.uk/introduction-to-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd-types/)